# Ext.Ajax.request with date

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using ExtJs and I need to pass a date in Ext.Ajax.request, but I dont know how can I do it. I am trying the following code:

```
dateController: function(botao){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: Webapp.link("research/2012-09-18T14:30:00/8"),
        method: 'get',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

The first one parameter in URL is the date and second one is the product id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
dateController: function(botao){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "YourUrl?research=2012-09-18T14:30:00",
        method: 'get',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Or you could do it using the params (*I never tried this with get, but it should work as well*)

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'YourUrl',
    method:'get', 
    params : {
       research: Ext.encode("2012-09-18T14:30:00")
    },
    scope : this,
    //method to call when the request is successful
    success : this.onSuccess,
    //method to call when the request is a failure
    failure : this.onFailure
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I decided pass a `Long` representing a timestamp to my controller, and there I convert in a Date, however, thank you so much for your help !